# Native NOT statement for handlebars

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

Is there a native not statement in handlebars, which would work with helper functions.

Something like {{#not helper param}} OK {{...

Comment: `unless` is not working for you?

Comment: Uncaught Error: unless doesn't match myFunction

Comment: Could you paste your entire code?

Comment: Sorry it's to complicated

Answer (score 0):

http://handlebarsjs.com/#unless

```
  {{#unless param}}
  <h1 class="warning">Yes it has</h1>
  {{/unless}}
```

Comment: I need with helper function, with parameters ... for now looks like there is nothing possible, as well chaining is not implemented, so I will probably go with ugly {{#helper param}} {{else}} OK {{/helper}}